# copying images and linking to them during make4ht conversion to HTML

Tags: make4ht

I use a command like this to generate HTML files and save them in the directory `./html`.

```
make4ht -x -f html5 -d html doc1.tex
```

So, for example, this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\includegraphics{../Figures/image.png}
\end{document}
```

when converted with the command above produces the file `./html/doc1.html` with contents as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='doc1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='doc1.tex' name='src' /> 
</head><body>
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='noindent'>This is a test. <img alt='PIC' src='../Figures/image.png' />
</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

What I'd like is for the img tag in the HTML file to point to the file `image.png` in the local directory i.e. `./html`, and to have the graphics file copied to `./html/image.png`.  This would allow me to zip up the `./html` directory and share it without having to worry about missing graphics files. Is this possible, and if so, how? I am using Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: How are you specifying the `../Figures` directory for the files in the .tex file? With `\graphicspath` or directly in `\includegraphics`, and are you using absolute or relative paths? Some sample code might help. This might be possible with supplying options for `t4ht`, and even if it's not possible through `make4ht`, it's almost certainly possible with a farily simple script. To be clear you don't want to copy the Figures directory to a subdirectory of `html/` but want the image files directly in `html/` itself? And what OS?

Comment: Good points - I've tried to clarify in the revised question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this build file:

```lua
local mkutils = require "mkutils"
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local process = domfilter{
  function(dom)
    for _, img in ipairs(dom:query_selector("img")) do
      local src = img:get_attribute("src")
      if src then
        -- remove path specification
        src = src:match("([^/]+)$")
        img:set_attribute("src", src)
      end
    end
    return dom
  end
}

local function image_copy(path, parameters)
  -- get image basename
  local basename = path:match("([^/]+)$")
  -- if outdir is empty, keep it empty, otherwise add / separator
  local outdir = parameters.outdir == "" and "" or parameters.outdir .. "/"
  -- handle trailing //
  outdir = outdir:gsub("//$","/")
  local output_file = outdir .. basename
  mkutils.cp(path, output_file)
end

Make:match("png$", function(path, parameters)
  image_copy(path, parameters)
  -- prevent further processing of the image
  return false
end)

Make:match("html$", process)
```

It does two things -- first, it removes file path from `<img src="path/image.png">`, second, it copies png images to the output directory.

If you want to make directory with all output files, including images, you can use this command:

```
make4ht -e build.lua -xd html doc1.tex
```

This is the resulting HTML:

```
<!--  l. 5  --><p class='noindent'>This is a test. <img alt='PIC' src='image.png' />
</p>
```

And directory listing of the `html` dir:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 michal michal 4411  7. zář 23.11 image.png
-rw-rw-r--. 1 michal michal 6067  7. zář 23.11 doc1.css
-rw-rw-r--. 1 michal michal  473  7. zář 23.11 doc1.html
```

Comment: This doesn't point to the Figures subdirectory (a specification I think I added after making the original post) but this still addresses the main point (creating a folder which can be zipped up and shared). Thanks for the excellent answer.

Comment: @GarethWalker ah, you are right. I've created my code before your edit and didn't inspect it too much, as it was already time to go to sleep. I can add support for subdirectories, if you are interested.

Comment: no worries - I've removed the requirement for subdirectories in the original post as this part is not so important (the IMG tags and copying the files were the crucial part)