# tex4ebook and \coverimage[someOptions]{AbsolutePath/someimage.jpg} does not work

Tags: graphics, paths, tex4ebook

I use tex4ebook with `\coverimage[someOptions]{AbsolutePath/someimage.jpg}` in the document, directly after `\begin{document}`. But the `AbsolutePath` is not respected and does not find someimage.jpg, respectively is not shown in the epub.

As AbsolutePath I use something like `C:/Somepath/folder/anotherfolder/someimage.jpg`. But in the epub no image is shown.

When I use `someimage.jpg` located in the current folder, where the `.tex` file is, it works and the someimage.jpg is shown in the epub.

Only the absolute path is not showing the image in the epub. But of cource the someimage.jpg is located in the AbsolutePath folder.

Is there anything to know that I miss?

It seems as if the

```
\graphicpath{{PathA/}{PathB/}{C:/folder/anotherfolder/}}
```

does not work with tex4ebook. Though it was said, that all options with `\includegraphics[]{}` will work with `\coverimage[]{}`.

Is there a fix to it?

Answer (score 1):

`tex4ebook` doesn't copy images, you need to do it using a build file. I've handled a similar case some time ago in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656511/2891), but it doesn't work correctly with `tex4ebook`. Here is a fixed version, which also contains other DOM filter that you want to use:

```lua
local mkutils = require "mkutils"
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local allowed_chars = {
  ["-"] = true,
  ["."] = true
}
local function fix_colons(id)
  -- match every non alphanum character
  return id:gsub("[%W]", function(s)
    -- some characters are allowed, we don't need to replace them
    if allowed_chars[s] then return s end
    -- in other cases, replace with underscore
    return "_"
  end)
end

local function id_colons(obj)
  -- replace : characters in links and ids with unserscores
  obj:traverse_elements(function(el) 
    local name = string.lower(obj:get_element_name(el))
    if name == "a" then
      local href = el:get_attribute("href")
      -- don't replace colons in external links
      if href and not href:match("[a-z]%://") then
        local base, id = href:match("(.*)%#(.*)")
        if base and id then
          id = fix_colons(id)
          el:set_attribute("href", base .. "#" .. id)
        end
      end
    end
    local id  = el:get_attribute("id")
    if id then
      el:set_attribute("id", fix_colons(id))
    end
  end)
  return obj
end

local function fix_img_names(dom)
    for _, img in ipairs(dom:query_selector("img")) do
        local src = img:get_attribute("src")
        if src then
            -- remove path specification
            src = src:match("([^/]+)$")
            img:set_attribute("src", src)
        end
    end
    return dom
end

local process = domfilter {id_colons,fix_img_names}


local function image_copy(path, parameters)
  -- get image basename
  local basename = path:match("([^/]+)$")
  -- if outdir is empty, keep it empty, otherwise add / separator
  local outdir = parameters.outdir == "" and "" or parameters.outdir .. "/"
  -- handle trailing //
  outdir = outdir:gsub("//$","/")
  local output_file = outdir .. basename
  for pos, name in pairs(Make.lgfile.files) do 
    if name == path then
      Make.lgfile.files[pos] = output_file
    end
  end
  mkutils.cp(path, output_file)
end

Make:match("png$", function(path, parameters)
  image_copy(path, parameters)
  -- prevent further processing of the image
  return false
end)

Make:match("jpg$", function(path, parameters)
  image_copy(path, parameters)
  -- prevent further processing of the image
  return false
end)


if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:xindy {modules={"duden-utf8"}}
  Make:biber {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end



Make:match("html$", process)
```

Details on how it works are in the link above.

Comment: Thank you Michal, you are a wonder. But I can not understand the code. You said yesterday, we could combine several build files together in one file. Right? So I think, I have at least 3 of them (in the meanwhile of the last 10 days). Should I just copy them in one file, one after the other? I do not quite understand this adding together.

Comment: @Thomkrates I've already added everything here, hopefully.

Comment: Yes, I was partially successful with it. When using `\graphicspath{}` of the `graphicx` package, I discovered that image file name with `-` in it, will not be found or as `not exists`. For example an image file with name `image-name.jpg` or `this-is-a-longer-image-name.jpg` will be found as `not exists`. Whereas `imagename.jpg` will get no error message and the generated epub will show the image file. Can you see this too? Or is there anything else with my system?

Comment: I set the absolute path of the imagename.jpg within `\coverimage[]{AbsolutPath/imagename.jpg}`. Then it generated an epub with no error runnig epubcheck. (In two of my projects). But with the same issues while using an imagename like `This-is-a-longer-image-name.jpg` (in another project) it does generate an epub without error code, but lacks the image in the epub and is not shown there. Additionally an error with epubcheck `"Absolutepath/This-is-a-longer-image-name.jpg" must be located in EPUB container`. Is this reproduceable by your system?

Comment: @Thomkrates no, filenames with `-` works for me, but I am on Linux. Do you use forward slashes in your file paths, or backslashes?

Comment: It was a mistake by me, the `-` seem not to be the problem. But I do not understand why I get discrepancies, since 2 of my sourcenameX.tex result in a epub with 0 error epubcheck. But with a third sourcenameY.tex it gives the error that the `im-age-na-me.jpg not exists`. And: No the slashes are correct in all paths the same. I really looked closely to the similarities between the 2 working sourcenameX.tex and hoped to get again a third epub with 0 error in epubcheck. But I can not find a hint where the difference is that is resulting in the error in epubcheck. - Any other ideas?

Comment: I have also issued a problem in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681968/epubcheck-with-error-while-using-tex4ebook-and-nocite-bibtexing for 20 errors in epubcheck concering `\pageref{somelabel}`. This is strange, since pageref appears in ordinary text body and nothing else with it. In the epub the pageref-number is a `non-functional hyperlink`, and therefore the error message with epubcheck `Fragmentbezeichner is missing`. What could here be missing?

Comment: @Thomkrates I will need MWEs for both of these issues,

Comment: Meanwhile I found out, that the error with epubcheck and the 20 pageref commands, has obviously nothing to do with the `-c myconfig.cfg` and the `-e build.lua` since a MWE with minimal `\pageref{}` and minimal `\index{}` and minimal `bibliography` did not reproduce the error in epubcheck. All minimal `pagerefs worked in the epub` (while in my sourcename.tex - with myconficg.cfg and build.lua the pageref in the epub do not work and do get 20 errors in epubcheck). So I will need to look at my `packages in sourcename.tex` and strategically look for the problem.

Comment: @Thomkrates yes, there needs to be something strange, because `\pageref` should work correctly. They probably point to some `\label` that is missing in the HTML file.

Comment: It is strange indeed. Since I used for the MWE the `same preamble` after `\documentclass` as in the sourcename.tex and the error in epubcheck could `not` be reproduced. I also looked in the html files for the `\label{somelabelx}` and checked the somelabelx within the sourcename.tex. But I could not find a lack of labels; all labels are present as pageref, for all pagerefs there is a label. I used the package `refcheck` and no warning can be found in the log file. But the 20 errors in epubcheck remain saying `Fragmentbezeichner ist nicht angegeben` (Some fragmented label is not specified).

Comment: Dear Michal, if you do not find a solution to this pageref-Situation-Problem (tex4ht?), I might be able to handle it with the program `sigil`. Do you know about it? It is said, that this is an `epub-editor`, which might be able to resolve the pageref-errors which result here via epubcheck. Do you think that could be possible?

Comment: @Thomkrates I cannot reproduce the issue, so it is hard for me to fix it :( I think it would be better to fix it in `tex4ebook`, because when you use manual edits, you would need to do them again when you recompile your book. Is it really not possible to make a MWE for this?

Comment: Yes, it would be better to fix it in tex4ebook. I do not know if it is not possible. But up to now it was not possible for me to reproduce the error (with epubcheck) in a MWE. Ok. I will try again to find a MWE, but I can not promise to be successful.

Comment: Dear Michal, see the new question: `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683283/errors-with-epubcheck-after-tex4ebook-concerning-pagerefsomelabel` for a MWE.