# Errors with epubcheck after tex4ebook, concerning \pageref{somelabel}

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook, epub, pageref

I found a MWE which reproduces the error message with epubcheck 2 times when having run tex4ebook (in my source the error appears 20 times identically) with `Fragmentbezeichner ist nicht angegeben` (transl.: "Fragmented label is not specified"). The error has to do with the `\pageref{somelabel}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[twoside,paperwidth=141mm,paperheight=211mm,top=11mm,includehead,bottom=19mm,outer=23mm,inner=18mm,bindingoffset=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp,datecirca=true,dateera=secular]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[continuous,page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\let\footnote=\pagenote
\newcommand*{\addtonotesnewcommand}[1]{%
    \ifpnhaschapter%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{chapter}\else%
    \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{chapter}}%
    \fi%
    \else%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{section}\else%
    \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{section}}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
    \addtonotes{\vspace*{0.7\baselineskip}\protect\noindent\vspace*{0.35\baselineskip}\textsc{\large #1}}%
}% by Michal H.
\renewcommand*{\notesname}{Anmerkungen und Verweise}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[xindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\else
\usepackage[]{imakeidx}
\fi
\makeindex
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[tex4ht,hyperindex=true,hyperfootnotes=true,
pdfauthor={Author},
pdftitle={Title},
pdfkeywords={Keywords}]{hyperref}
\else\fi
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
Some text\label{text} for the first\label{first} page: \fullcite{sigfridsson}

\clearpage
\section{Second Section}
The error happens with epubcheck: Fragmentbezeichner ist nicht angegeben.

"`sind einige so umsichtig, dass sie, ohne sich eine Blöße zu geben, durch ein hämisches Lächeln, durch ein Kichern, durch eine gewisse harmlose Boshaftigkeit, das, was sie nicht imstande waren, mit Gründen zu beweisen, und was sie nicht einmal sich selbst einreden können, mit solchen kleinen Kunstgriffen höflicher Verachtung die Ignoranz, die in jedem anderen Falle offenbar würde, nicht nur bei sich verdecken, sondern sie dem Gegner anlasten wollen; denn sie kommen nicht zum Disputieren, um die Wahrheit zu finden oder zu suchen, sondern um des Sieges willen, und um gelehrter zu scheinen und als eifrigere Verfechter des Gegenteils."'\footfullcite[Siehe][Seite 19]{sigfridsson}\label{ZitatGiordanoBrunoEins} Dies ein Zitat \index{Bruno@Bruno, Giordano}Giordano Brunos. 

\clearpage

So aber gebärden sich grausame Charaktere des Hasses und der Verachtung, wie dies Giordano Bruno\index{Bruno@Bruno, Giordano} in den vorherigen Zitaten auf den Seiten \pageref{ZitatGiordanoBrunoEins} und \pageref{ZitatGiordanoBrunoZwei} beschrieben hatte.

\clearpage

"`Wozu es wahrlich heroischen Sinnes bedurfte, um nicht die Arme sinken zu lassen, zu verzweifeln und überwältigt zu werden von solch reißendem Strom gemeinster Verleumdungen, wie sie über mich ergossen wurden von dem Neid der Unwissenden, der Anmaßung der Sophisten, der Lästersucht der Böswilligen, dem Getuschel der Diener, dem Murren der Lohnarbeiter, den Nörgeleien der Dienstboten, den Unterstellungen der Dummköpfe, den Verdächtigungen der Spitzel, dem Übereifer der Heuchler, der Missgunst der Ungebildeten, der Wut des Pöbels, dem Zorn des Gesindels, den Klagen der Benachteiligten und dem Geschrei der Gezüchtigten; es fehlte nur noch die Empörung von Seiten aufgebrachter, verstiegener und gehässiger Weiber, deren falsche Tränen wirkungsvoller zu sein pflegen als noch so hohe Wogen und Stürme der Anmaßung, Neid, Lästersucht, Murren, Verrat, Zorn, Empörung, Hass und Wut."'\footfullcite[Siehe][Seite 5f]{sigfridsson}\label{ZitatGiordanoBrunoZwei}

\printnotes

\printindex

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What might be a fixing for it?

If you can not reproduce the error with this file, I would probably need to let you know about the files `-c myconfig.cfg` and `-e mybuild.lua`. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution due to my needs:

```
\newcounter{cnttextlabels}% in the preamble of sourcename.tex

\refstepcounter{cnttextlabels}\label{Somelabel}
% Always at the position in the text body where the reference should point at.

\pageref{Somelabel}
% Used in text for page-references to refer to the appropriate label in a text position where no other counter need to be refered to.
```

This reduced the errors in epubcheck from 20 to 0 (zero) and made it valide. And I tested the page-reference sporadically and found that they work correctly (which wasnt before this answer not the case, due to the 20 error in epubcheck which gave 20 non-functional pagerefering hyperlinks)

The problem was, that I neither needed to label the `\footfullcite[][]{}` nor any other  `\section{}` which all seem to have counters.

So I defined a new counter for my `labeling within arbitrary text passages`, like quotes or defintions of special content that might be good refering to (and has no counter up to the new one cnttextlabels).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `\label` inside your `\footullcite` commands, like in:

```
\footfullcite[Siehe][Seite 19\label{ZitatGiordanoBrunoEins}]{sigfridsson}
```

You need to use it inside the footnote, because otherwise the `\label` is used on the wrong page.

This is the fixed document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[twoside,paperwidth=141mm,paperheight=211mm,top=11mm,includehead,bottom=19mm,outer=23mm,inner=18mm,bindingoffset=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp,datecirca=true,dateera=secular]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[continuous,page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\let\footnote=\pagenote
\newcommand*{\addtonotesnewcommand}[1]{%
    \ifpnhaschapter%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{chapter}\else%
    \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{chapter}}%
    \fi%
    \else%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{section}\else%
    \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{section}}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
    \addtonotes{\vspace*{0.7\baselineskip}\protect\noindent\vspace*{0.35\baselineskip}\textsc{\large #1}}%
}% by Michal H.
\renewcommand*{\notesname}{Anmerkungen und Verweise}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[xindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\else
\usepackage[]{imakeidx}
\fi
\makeindex
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[tex4ht,hyperindex=true,hyperfootnotes=true,
pdfauthor={Author},
pdftitle={Title},
pdfkeywords={Keywords}]{hyperref}
\else\fi
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
Some text\label{text} for the first\label{first} page: \fullcite{sigfridsson}

\clearpage
\section{Second Section}
The error happens with epubcheck: Fragmentbezeichner ist nicht angegeben.

"`sind einige so umsichtig, dass sie, ohne sich eine Blöße zu geben, durch ein hämisches Lächeln, durch ein Kichern, durch eine gewisse harmlose Boshaftigkeit, das, was sie nicht imstande waren, mit Gründen zu beweisen, und was sie nicht einmal sich selbst einreden können, mit solchen kleinen Kunstgriffen höflicher Verachtung die Ignoranz, die in jedem anderen Falle offenbar würde, nicht nur bei sich verdecken, sondern sie dem Gegner anlasten wollen; denn sie kommen nicht zum Disputieren, um die Wahrheit zu finden oder zu suchen, sondern um des Sieges willen, und um gelehrter zu scheinen und als eifrigere Verfechter des Gegenteils."'\footfullcite[Siehe][Seite 19\label{ZitatGiordanoBrunoEins}]{sigfridsson} Dies ein Zitat \index{Bruno@Bruno, Giordano}Giordano Brunos. 

\clearpage

So aber gebärden sich grausame Charaktere des Hasses und der Verachtung, wie dies Giordano Bruno\index{Bruno@Bruno, Giordano} in den vorherigen Zitaten auf den Seiten \pageref{ZitatGiordanoBrunoEins} und \pageref{ZitatGiordanoBrunoZwei} beschrieben hatte.

\clearpage

"`Wozu es wahrlich heroischen Sinnes bedurfte, um nicht die Arme sinken zu lassen, zu verzweifeln und überwältigt zu werden von solch reißendem Strom gemeinster Verleumdungen, wie sie über mich ergossen wurden von dem Neid der Unwissenden, der Anmaßung der Sophisten, der Lästersucht der Böswilligen, dem Getuschel der Diener, dem Murren der Lohnarbeiter, den Nörgeleien der Dienstboten, den Unterstellungen der Dummköpfe, den Verdächtigungen der Spitzel, dem Übereifer der Heuchler, der Missgunst der Ungebildeten, der Wut des Pöbels, dem Zorn des Gesindels, den Klagen der Benachteiligten und dem Geschrei der Gezüchtigten; es fehlte nur noch die Empörung von Seiten aufgebrachter, verstiegener und gehässiger Weiber, deren falsche Tränen wirkungsvoller zu sein pflegen als noch so hohe Wogen und Stürme der Anmaßung, Neid, Lästersucht, Murren, Verrat, Zorn, Empörung, Hass und Wut."'\footfullcite[Siehe][Seite 5f\label{ZitatGiordanoBrunoZwei}]{sigfridsson}

\printnotes

\printindex

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, if this is the solution. I could not imagine what might be the fix for it. But this seems easy, also for you, isnt it? I will come back and report if this works for all the 20 errors left with epubcheck. But it seems to be. Thank you so much for your continuous help und understanding of the cases I brought up the last weeks. You always found a fix for it.

Comment: @Thomkrates this one was fortunately quite easy, I immediatelly knew that labels outside footnote will be placed on a different page.

Comment: As far as I see, I used `\label{somelabel}` out of its intended use. Since I do sometimes not label a `\section` or something numbered, but I wanted to use it as a `marked postion in text` for example for a `quote` or a `certain amount of special text or topic`, to refer with `\pageref` to this quoting text oder special topic which is not numbers and has no counter. So I need perhaps some other workaround or package to handle `labeling of text` instead of numbered objects.

Comment: See my own answer. I did not need to label the `footfullcite` but `arbitrary text passages like definitions, quotes, special content without counter but worth refering to`.